# Write "everything" to the log file?

Tags: logging

A few weeks ago I stumbled upon a command that wrote “everything” (spaces used, paragraphs, rules, etc.) about how each page in the document was typeset. But now I can’t remember what it was. Can you help me?

Comment: `\showoutput`?..

Comment: or `\tracingall` if you want lots of information (this can easily add hundreds of thousands of lines to the log, use with care....)

Comment: Or just `\loggingall` to have it only go to the log file.